# Why does one TableView sort and not the other?

Tags: java, sorting, javafx, tableview, fxml

Disclaimer: I figured out how to make this work but I'm hoping someone can help me understand why it didn't work my original way.

I have two TableViews that the user will be able to move items back and forth using an Add and Remove button. My "Available" TableView gets populated using an ObservableList retrieved from the database. My "Selected" TableView gets populated by parsing a string of comma separated values (sent from another controller). When I select one of the items in the "Available" TableView and click "Add" it gets added to the "Selected" TableView and is sorted correctly. When I select one of the items in the "Selected" TableView and click "Remove" it gets added to the "Available" TableView but it gets added to the end and isn't sorted correctly.

As a test I changed the population of the "Available" TableView to parse the ObservableList and add each item similar to the way the "Selected" list was populated and then when I clicked Remove, the item gets added to the "Available" TableView and is sorted correctly.

So I'm hoping someone wouldn't mind helping me understand why it had to be this way and maybe suggest better way if mine isn't efficient.

**TwoTablesView.fxml:**

```
<?import javafx.geometry.Insets?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TableView?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.HBox?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.VBox?>

<AnchorPane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="248.0" prefWidth="422.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.171" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="twotables.TwoTablesController">
   <children>
      <HBox prefHeight="240.0" prefWidth="600.0">
         <children>
            <TableView fx:id="availableMRTsTableView" prefHeight="240.0" prefWidth="150.0">
               <columns>
                  <TableColumn fx:id="availableColumn" prefWidth="150.0" text="Available MRTs" />
               </columns>
               <HBox.margin>
                  <Insets left="10.0" />
               </HBox.margin>
            </TableView>
            <VBox alignment="CENTER" spacing="10.0">
               <children>
                  <Button alignment="TOP_CENTER" maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#onAdd" text="Add --&gt;" />
                  <Button alignment="TOP_CENTER" maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#onRemove" text="&lt;-- Remove" />
               </children>
               <opaqueInsets>
                  <Insets />
               </opaqueInsets>
               <HBox.margin>
                  <Insets bottom="10.0" left="10.0" right="10.0" top="10.0" />
               </HBox.margin>
            </VBox>
            <TableView fx:id="selectedMRTsTableView" prefHeight="240.0" prefWidth="150.0">
               <columns>
                  <TableColumn fx:id="selectedColumn" prefWidth="150.0" text="Selected MRTs" />
               </columns>
               <HBox.margin>
                  <Insets right="10.0" />
               </HBox.margin>
            </TableView>
         </children>
      </HBox>
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

**TwoTablesController.java:**

```
package twotables;

import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;
import javafx.beans.property.ReadOnlyStringWrapper;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.SelectionMode;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;

public class TwoTablesController implements Initializable
{
    @FXML
    private TableView<String> availableMRTsTableView;
    @FXML
    private TableView<String> selectedMRTsTableView;
    @FXML
    private TableColumn<String, String> availableColumn;
    @FXML
    private TableColumn<String, String> selectedColumn;
    private ObservableList<String> availableList;
    private ObservableList<String> selectedList;

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
        // This will allow the table to select multiple rows at once
        availableMRTsTableView.getSelectionModel().setSelectionMode(
                SelectionMode.MULTIPLE);
        selectedMRTsTableView.getSelectionModel().setSelectionMode(
                SelectionMode.MULTIPLE);

        // Add Cell Value Factory
        availableColumn.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> 
                new ReadOnlyStringWrapper(cellData.getValue())
        );
        selectedColumn.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> 
                new ReadOnlyStringWrapper(cellData.getValue())
        );

        // Make it sortable
        availableMRTsTableView.getSortOrder().add(availableColumn);
        selectedMRTsTableView.getSortOrder().add(selectedColumn);

        // Get rid of the "no content" when the table is empty
        availableMRTsTableView.setPlaceholder(new Label(""));
        selectedMRTsTableView.setPlaceholder(new Label(""));

        // This was the original way I tried to populate the Table. If I
        // populate the table like the following, the sorting doesn't work
        //availableMRTsTableView.setItems(availableList);

        // populate the Column lists (this will be coming from the database)
        availableList = FXCollections.<String>observableArrayList("AA","DD","FF");
        availableList.forEach(mrt -> {
            availableMRTsTableView.getItems().add(mrt);
        });

        // real code would be calling this from another controller
        setSelectedMRTs(new String("BB,CC,EE"));
    }    

    @FXML
    private void onAdd(ActionEvent event)
    {
        // Get the columns selected
        ObservableList<String> userSelection = availableMRTsTableView.
                getSelectionModel().getSelectedItems();

        // Add the columns to the Selected MRTs Table
        selectedMRTsTableView.getItems().addAll(userSelection);

        // Remove the columns from the Available MRTs Table
        availableMRTsTableView.getItems().removeAll(userSelection);

        // Sort the Tables
        availableMRTsTableView.sort();
        selectedMRTsTableView.sort();

        // Clear the selections form the table
        availableMRTsTableView.getSelectionModel().clearSelection();
    }

    @FXML
    private void onRemove(ActionEvent event) {
        // Get the columns selected
        ObservableList<String> userSelection = selectedMRTsTableView.
                getSelectionModel().getSelectedItems();

        // Add the columns to the Available MRTs Table
        availableMRTsTableView.getItems().addAll(userSelection);

        // Remove the columns from the Selected MRTs Table
        selectedMRTsTableView.getItems().removeAll(userSelection);

        // Sort the Tables
        availableMRTsTableView.sort();
        selectedMRTsTableView.sort();

        // Clear the selections form the table
        selectedMRTsTableView.getSelectionModel().clearSelection();
    }

    public void setSelectedMRTs(String mrtString)
    {
        String mrt;

        // Populate the table
        StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(mrtString,",");
        while (st.hasMoreTokens())
        {
            mrt = st.nextToken();

            // Remove column from the Available Columns Table
            availableMRTsTableView.getItems().remove(mrt);

            // Add column to the Selected Columns Table
            selectedMRTsTableView.getItems().add(mrt);
        }

        // Sort the tables
        availableMRTsTableView.sort();
        selectedMRTsTableView.sort();
    }
}
```

**TwoTables.java:**

```
package labelbindtest;

import javafx.application.Application;
import static javafx.application.Application.launch;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class LabelBindTest extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("FXMLDocument.fxml"));
        Scene scene = new Scene(root);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

(And look @Slaw, I got the formatting right on my post this time lol)

Comment: Please include a description that allows us to reproduce the issue. Unless I click on one of the columns to remove/invert the sorting, the item order is fine when I tried to reproduce the issue...

Comment: @fabien I added a comment. Sorry my original one didn't indicate it clearly